How to open File Explorer and camera for make photo via the Android app
I'm a beginner. I am writing one Android studio (Koala) application a simple messenger, and I need to be able to select an image from the gallery and open it in my application and open camera for make a photo (example to send it). Thank`s
i`ve tried search how open camera, but when i write code and debug app, i get mistake
package com.task;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.util.Objects;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final ImageView image = findViewById(R.id.cameraImage);


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        @SuppressLint("WrongViewCast") Button cam = findViewById(R.id.camera);
        cam.setOnClickListener(this::onClick);

    }

    public void onClickHistory(View view){
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivityHistory.class));
    }
    public void onClickExplorer(View view){
        // TODO:
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        if (data != null) {
            bitmap = (Bitmap) Objects.requireNonNull(data.getExtras()).get("data");
        }
        image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }

    private void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}


This solution does not need your app to ask the user any permissions at all.
To pick photo from gallery:
// Registers a photo picker activity launcher in single-select mode.
ActivityResultLauncher<PickVisualMediaRequest> pickMedia = registerForActivityResult(new PickVisualMedia(), uri -> {
    // Callback is invoked after the user selects a media item or closes the
    // photo picker.
    if (uri != null) {
        Log.d("PhotoPicker", "Selected URI: " + uri);
    } else {
        Log.d("PhotoPicker", "No media selected");
    }
});
// Launch the photo picker and let the user choose only images.
pickMedia.launch(new PickVisualMediaRequest.Builder()
        .setMediaType(PickVisualMedia.ImageOnly.INSTANCE)
        .build());

Visit Photo Picker for more info.
To capture image from camera:
ImageCapture imageCapture =
    new ImageCapture.Builder()
        .setTargetRotation(view.getDisplay().getRotation())
        .build();

cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(lifecycleOwner, cameraSelector, imageCapture, imageAnalysis, preview);
// Then trigger following on some button click
ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions outputFileOptions =
            new ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(new File(...)).build();
    imageCapture.takePicture(outputFileOptions, cameraExecutor,
        new ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onImageSaved(ImageCapture.OutputFileResults outputFileResults) {
                // insert your code here.
            }
            @Override
            public void onError(ImageCaptureException error) {
                // insert your code here.
            }
       }
    );

Visit Image Capture for more info.

Do I need to request permissions in the manifest?

No permissions required at all.

Keep this permission as per new Update for Android 14
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="32" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="29" />

Code in Activity
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ProfileActivity.this);

                builder.setMessage("Select image from camera or gallery?")
                        .setCancelable(true)
                        .setPositiveButton("Camera", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                strFrom = "Camera";
                                dialog.cancel();
                                Permissions();
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("Gallery", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                strFrom = "Gallery";
                                dialog.cancel();
                                Permissions();
                            }
                        });

                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();

        }
    });

public void Permissions() {
    boolean permissions = CheckPermissions();
    if (permissions) {
        if (strFrom.equalsIgnoreCase("Gallery")) {
            pickImageFromGallery();
        } else {
            takePhoto();
        }

    } else {
        CheckPermissions();
    }
}

private void pickImageFromGallery() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE_FROM_GALLERY);
}
private void takePhoto() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE_FROM_Camera);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Camera app not available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}


private boolean CheckPermissions() {
    /*String permission1 = Manifest.permission.CAMERA;
    String permission2 = READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;
    String permission3 = WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(ProfileActivity.this, permission1) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(ProfileActivity.this, permission1) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(ProfileActivity.this, permission3) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ProfileActivity.this, new String[]{permission1, permission2,permission3}, 1000);
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }*/

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
        String[] permissionstorage = {Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES, Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES};
        int permissions = PermissionChecker.checkSelfPermission(ProfileActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES);
        if (permissions != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ProfileActivity.this, permissionstorage, 1000);
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        String[] permissionstorage = {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
        int permissions = PermissionChecker.checkSelfPermission(ProfileActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        if (permissions != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ProfileActivity.this, permissionstorage, 1000);
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

}
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 123 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        storageManager = StorageManager.getInstance(ProfileActivity.this);
        Uri selectedFileUri = data.getData();
        onFileSelected(selectedFileUri,data.getData().getPath().toString());
    }else if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (userpick)
            {
                if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_FROM_GALLERY) {
                    Uri imageUri = data.getData();
                    try {
                        Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);
                        UserImage64 = encodeImage(bitmap);
                        ivProfilePic.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                } else if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_FROM_Camera) {
                    Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                    if (extras != null) {
                        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
                        UserImage64 = encodeImage(imageBitmap);
                        ivProfilePic.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
                    }
                }
            }

        }


}

